# How to make another elements under 100% heigth img?

Tags: html, css

So I started week ago learning HTML,CSS and I tried to make website that has only 1 page which has the "main view" at first and then if you roll down the page you will see another details of the company work here is what im trying to do :  The 1 means the first view when you enter the website, the 2 means after you roll down a little bit and the third is the end of the page after you roll [image: The 1 means the first view when you enter the website, the 2 means after you roll down a little bit and the third is the end of the page after you roll] ,
 I tried using :

```html
margin-bottom: -150px;
```

but it became very confusing and felt to me as im doing something that isn't professional because if I will build a long page it will become at the end about -900px , I hope you got my question if not I will try to explain better.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel.

Comment: What do you mean by "roll down"? Scroll down? I'm having a hard time to understand what your question is. In order to place boxes on top of each other it should be sufficient to just put them into the page like `<div>1</div><div>2</div>` without any CSS neccessary. Could you please add your code?

Comment: You should give a clearer explanation of what you are trying to achieve and what code you have tried (more than just a `margin`). If I get it right you want `number 1` as seen in photo to take the full height of the browser window, `number 2` to take the full height of the browser window again but if page is scrolled down and `number 3` same as `number 2`. Please, update the question so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for your case

```css
.main-page {
  background-color: #000;
}

.first,
.second,
.third {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: blue;
}

.third {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-page">
  <div class="first">1</div>
  <div class="second">2</div>
  <div class="third">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, that's exctaly what I wanted Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

**Based on my comment.**

If that is the expected behavior you can do it by setting the containers' height to `height: 100vh`. As I mentioned in my comment, you should, *for sure*, include more of your code and a clearer explanation.